# fglrx driver doesn't start DRI in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, xorg, amd-radeon

I have a Toshiba Satellite P745D-SP4161M laptop with a AMD Radeon HD 6620G graphics card and a AMD A8-3500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics APU. I have dual boot with Windows 7 and Debian Wheezy/Sid.

I currently have a problem with the ATI propetary drivers. The Catalyst Control Center (amdcccle) and aticonfig are working fine, however glxgears, glxinfo, fglrxinfo and fgl_glxgears produce the following output:

`root@debian:/home/mirath# fglrxinfo 
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  13
  Current serial number in output stream:  13`

Also, these warnings and errors appear in the Xorg.0.log:

```
root@debian:/home/mirath# cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep '([WE][WE])'
[   444.801] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   444.801] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   444.801] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   444.801] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   444.801] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   444.801] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType".
[   444.833] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[   444.845] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:1:1) found
[   444.942] (WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
[   444.942] (WW) fglrx(0): Hasn't establisted DRM connection
[   444.942] (WW) fglrx(0): No DRM connection for driver fglrx.
[   445.064] (EE) fglrx(0): atiddxDriScreenInit failed, GPS not been initialized. 
[   445.064] (WW) fglrx(0): ***********************************************************
[   445.064] (WW) fglrx(0): * DRI initialization failed                               *
[   445.064] (WW) fglrx(0): * kernel module (fglrx.ko) may be missing or incompatible *
[   445.064] (WW) fglrx(0): * 2D and 3D acceleration disabled                         *
[   445.064] (WW) fglrx(0): ***********************************************************
[   445.083] (WW) fglrx(0): Textured Video not supported without DRI enabled.
[   445.084] (EE) fglrx(0): XMM failed to open CMMQS connection.(EE) fglrx(0): 
[   445.084] (EE) fglrx(0): XMM failed to initialize
[   445.084] (WW) fglrx(0): No XV video playback available
[   445.084] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "VendorName" is not used
[   445.084] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "ModelName" is not used
```

My xorg.conf is this:

```
root@debian:/home/mirath# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "UseFastTLS" "1"
    BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The grub entry for my kernel is this:

```
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3c0acf7c-d560-4793-ada2-4e7bb6a444bb
        echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=UUID=c617f223-8c25-4e58-a4a2-faf1c0b3f335 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
}
```

This is my uname -a output:

```
root@debian:/home/mirath# uname -a
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 3 03:41:26 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!!!  My computer is a Toshiba Satellite P745D-SP4161M with an Atheros AR9285 wireless card and an AMD Radeon HD 6620G graphics card. 
I installed the 3.2-rc1 kernel form kernel.org. I used the method for installing kernels shown [here](https://systemsaviour.com/2011/05/16/amd-fusion-e-350-debian-wheezy-testing-with-catalyst-11-5-drivers/). After doing that, the wireless died, so I activated some kernel options in the 3.2 kernel and everything works fine now.

These are the kernel options I activated, they are found in Device Drivers -> Network device support -> Wireless LAN -> Atheros Wireless Cards:

```
CONFIG_ATH9K_PCI
CONFIG_ATH9K_AHB
CONFIG_ATH9K_DEBUGFS
CONFIG_ATH9K_RATE_CONTROL
```

This is the code for compiling the kernel, is based on the link I provided:

```
$ wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2-rc1.tar.bz2
$ tar jxf linux-3.2-rc1.tar.bz2
$ cd linux-3.2-rc1
$ make menuconfig #If you are going to do something to the kernel...
$ make-kpkg -j2 --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --bzimage kernel_headers kernel_image
$ sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb #make sure you don't have any other .deb in the parent directory.
```